# midi record to score

Tags: software, recording, midi

I am looking for a midi recording and score printing software for my IPad.

I have :

- Ipad.
- EPiano with Midi Ports.
- Midi connector box with cables, which works fine with "Home Orchestra".

Now I am looking for a simple Software to record my played keys to a score, which I could save as pdf or something similar.

What IPad-App do experts suggest me ?

Comment: Be prepared, that recording something in Midi format and afterwards printing that as score  gives something between disappointing (much effort required for fixing mis"understandings") and unusable results. Reasons are given [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/10461/2600).

Comment: Whilst not an answer to your question, there are several desktop/laptop applications that are well suited to your requirements (Sibelius, Finale, Musescore, etc), taking into account the already mentioned issues with MIDI conversion. Perhaps you should consider whether the iPad is the right tool for this job?

Comment: I can imagine that, but do you have any suggestion for IPad ? I just need to create small scores for my little child. IPad would be small enough to have beside the epiano and midi cables I have already bougth.

Comment: I just bought notion. Not bad, but it doesn't meet my wish. Is it true, that it can't record live with metronom. You have to choose the correct note and then the keybord is only a tool to add notes. Is there no Ipad software that records live with a metronom. First hand and after second hand for example.